# Initialize a MultiObjectPicker

Tags: rally

If I have an array of "names", how can I initialize a MultiObjectPicker to have those values selected?  I have a string array that's a set of Release.Name

```
{
    xtype: 'rallymultiobjectpicker',
    modelType: 'release',
    itemId: 'rankingreleasepicker',
    fieldLabel: 'Select releases: ',
    listeners: {
        blur: this._runQuery,
        render: function( ctrl, eOpts) {ctrl.setValue(this.releaseNames)}, //does not work
        scope: this
    },
    storeConfig: {
        filters: [
            {
                property: 'State',
                operator: '!=',
                value: 'Accepted'
            }
        ],
        context: dataContext
    },
    value: this.releaseNames //does not work
},
```

Comment: I've also tried trying to setValue using _refs, objectID, using Stateful, the full object from getValue, just the data object, and nothing works.  Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiobject picker setValue takes a model as the input.  The easiest thing to do is to create a quick and dirty model to put in the values you want, so the following example works for me.  The release ObjectIDs are mine, of course, and I've commented out things I didn't stub:

```
    Ext.define('PickerRelease',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [ 
          { name: '_ref', type:'string' }
        ]
    });

    this.releaseNames = [
       Ext.create('PickerRelease',{ _ref: '/release/731448'} ),
       Ext.create('PickerRelease',{ _ref: '/release/731459'} )
    ];

    this.down('#display_box').add({
        xtype: 'rallymultiobjectpicker',
        modelType: 'release',
        itemId: 'rankingreleasepicker',
        fieldLabel: 'Select releases: ',
        listeners: {
            //blur: this._runQuery,
            //render: function( ctrl, eOpts) {ctrl.setValue(this.releaseNames)}, //does not work
            scope: this
        },
        storeConfig: {
            filters: [
                {
                    property: 'State',
                    operator: '!=',
                    value: 'Accepted'
                }
            ],
            //context: dataContext
        },
        value: this.releaseNames //does not work
    });
```

Comment: This code may not do what you want when dealing with more than one project. Different projects may have release objects with the same name and dates, but different oids.

Comment: Fair enough, if a release name is used in more than one project (even a child project) the object IDs are going to be different.  So a more generic response to the request might be to create a store to go get the values to put into this.releaseNames.  Or, even more fun, perhaps to add a listener to the storeConfig that ferrets out the objects returned and tie them to the names, using setValue at that point.